# how to test react native code with jest and mock for firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, jes

I am trying to test react native method using jest , my problem is the revised value is not the same as expected value . because the function use firebase i made mock 
so this is the method i want to use

```
 insertUserAction= async  ()=>{
 console.log("inside inserUserAction")
 var userActionKey =firebase.database().ref().child('userActions').push().key;
 firebase.database().ref('userActions/'+userActionKey).set(
  {

  userID: firebase.auth().currentUser.uid,
  ActionID:'001',
  time:new Date().getHours(),
  day:moment().format('dddd'),
  Repetition:'1',
  inRoutine:'0',
  insertedDate: new Date().getFullYear()+'/'+new Date().getMonth()+'/'+new Date().getDate(),
  })

  .then(() => {
    console.log("enter then");

    this.setState(() =>{
      return {
      userID:firebase.auth().currentUser.uid,
      ActionID:'001',
      time:new Date().getHours(),
      day:moment().format('dddd'),
      Repetition:'1'}
    });
      console.log('inserted')
  }).catch((error)=>{
      console.log(error)
  });
 }
```

and here the firebase configuration

```
   const firebaseConfig = {


  apiKey: "******",
  authDomain: "*****",
  databaseURL: "*****",
  projectId: "*****",
  storageBucket: "*******",
  messagingSenderId: "******",
  appId: "*****",
  };
```

and here the test

```
    import React from 'react';
    import HomeScreen from     '../screens/HomeScreen';

   import renderer from 'react-test-renderer';

  jest.mock("firebase/app", () => {
  const data = { ActionID: "unnamed" };
  const snapshot = { val: () => data };
  return {
    firebaseConfig: jest.fn().mockReturnValue({
    database: jest.fn().mockReturnValue({
      ref: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
      once: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve(snapshot))
    })
  })
};
 });

test('testing Analysis feature ', () => {
 const component = renderer.create(<HomeScreen ActionID="5" />);
 const instance = component.getInstance();
 instance.insertUserAction();
 expect(instance.state.ActionID).toBe("001");
  });
```

I am not sure with the mock

Comment: You are using firebase.auth(), so you should mock that method too, maybe it's hard trying mock the library, you probably can use some firebase mock library out there, maybe firebase-mock npm package can help you to do that,

Comment: even i delete firebase.auth() it did not work

Comment: that's because you are using others method too, like child, push, set, so be careful what you need to mock to get your test work

Comment: can you show me hoe to mock these functions too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see, it's not necessary to mock the firebaseConfig, because this is only needed to connect to real db, but for mock purpose it not needed, so basically you only need to mock what you really need, in this case you need something like this:

```
jest.mock("firebase/app", () => {
  const data = { ActionID: "unnamed" };
  const snapshot = { val: () => data };
  return {
    firebaseConfig: jest.fn().mockReturnValue({}),
    auth: jest.fn().mockReturnValue({ currentUser: { uid: 'uid' } }),
    database: jest.fn().mockReturnValue({
      ref: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => ({
        child: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => ({
          push: jest.fn().mockReturnValue({
            key: 'someValueAsKey'
          })
        })),
        set: jest.fn(),
      })),
      once: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve(snapshot))
    })
  };
});
```

I kept the `firebaseConfig` mock, because I didn't want to remove your code, if you want you can remove it.

remember that you can use some firebase mock libraries, like this one https://www.npmjs.com/package/firebase-mock

I hope this can help you.